# Invalid language element: [variable]

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, qtspim

Currently coding an assembly language assignment. I originally coded it with pseudo enabled in the MARS compiler and then translated the pseudo commands one by one. Currently I am having trouble with getting an error message "Invalid Language Element: [str1]". This is just a small portion of my code.

```
 1|.data
 2|val1: .word 1    #0x10010000
 3|val2: .word 2    #0x10010004
 4|val3: .word 3    #0x10010008
 5|name:    .asciiz "Jacob McDonald"    #0x1001000C length 15
 6|str1:    .asciiz "Enter a number: "  #0x1001001B length 17
 7|newln:   .asciiz "\n"            #0x1001002C
 8|.globl main
 9|.text
10|main:
11|addi $16, $0, 23             #Load 23 into $s0 
12|addi $2, $0, 4                #Set syscall command 4, print string 
13|lui $1, 4097 [str1]           #Load string to be printed to queue 
14|ori $4, $1, 27 [str1]    
15|syscall                      #syscall print string str1
```

I'm not sure what I need to fix as the code will execute fine if I run it through qtSpim, but will not execute and will relay the error message "Invalid Language Element: [str1]"

Is the error being caused how I wrote lines 13 and 14? Do I need to address the actual hex addresses instead of the .asciiz name?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: `[str1]` isn't supposed to be there. `lui` takes exactly two operands; a register and an immediate. There's no form of `lui` that looks like `lui $reg, imm [foo]`.

Similarly, `ori` takes exactly three operands, and the `[str1]` at the end of the line is garbage that isn't supposed to be there.

(I'm assuming that the `1|`, `2|`, etc strings aren't in your actual source code file, because that would also be a problem)